# woocommerce code for cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need to add the woocommerce cart button to one of my pages and was wondering if someone could help with the code required to call the cart button. Here is the current code:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

<?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="product-image1">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
  <?php echo $product->get_image(); ?>
</a>
</div>
<div id="product-description-container">
  <ul>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
    <li><h4><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></h4></li></a>
    <li><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt )?></li>
    <li><h6><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>  **MISSING CODE TO ADD TO CART BUTTON HERE**</h6></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think may be you need following code.

Add this code to your place = (`**MISSING CODE TO ADD TO CART BUTTON HERE**`).

```
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->get_type() ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Worked like a glove!

Comment: $product->id should now be replaced by $product->get_id()  and $product->product_type by $product->get_type(), otherwise you get an error.

Comment: If I put the get_price_html before this code I get a fatal error, any idea why?

Comment: How can I change text add to cart to added to cart after click this?